# Creating application tutorial on a separate layer

Tags: android

I would like to create a "tutorial"/overview on how to use my application, very similar to this one:

[image]

[image]

Are there any libraries I could use to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library, its called

[showcase view](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView)

You can add it with Gradle

```
compile 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.0.0'
```

It uses the builder pattern to do its thing

```
new ShowcaseView.Builder(this)
    .setTarget(new ActionViewTarget(this, ActionViewTarget.Type.HOME))
    .setContentTitle("ShowcaseView")
    .setContentText("This is highlighting the Home button")
    .hideOnTouchOutside()
    .build();
```